# How to sort this type of nested array in PHP (on the basis of timestamp at index no. 6)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to PHP multi-dimentional arrays, So I need 100% working answer please...

I had tried it by using muli-sort and usort function but they are not working for me, honestly i didn't know how to use them in case of multi-dimentional arrays!

In my case (how I am implementing multi-sort), it is only sorting the first day's array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Cycling
            [1] => 03:30 PM-04:00 PM
            [2] => Criterium International
            [3] => 0.5
            [4] => SN1
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459524600
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => Rugby
            [1] => 03:00 PM-05:15 PM
            [2] => Super League Rugby - Wolves v Warriors
            [3] => 2.25
            [4] => SNOverflow
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459522800 
        ) 
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => Rugby 
            [1] => 05:00am-07:30 AM 
            [2] => National Rugby League Titans vs Broncos
            [3] => 2.5 
            [4] => SNWorld
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459485000 
        )
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Rugby
            [1] => 09:45 AM-12:00 PM
            [2] => Super League Rugby - Red Devils v E
            [3] => 2.25
            [4] => SNOverflow
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459590300 
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Rugby
            [1] => 12:00 PM-02:00 PM
            [2] => Super League Rugby - Vikings v Dragons
            [3] => 2
            [4] => SNOverflow
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459598400 
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => BPL Soccer
            [1] => 07:30 AM-09:45 AM
            [2] => Aston Villa v Chelsea
            [3] => 2.25
            [4] => SNRegions
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459582200
        )
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => The Wheel Highlights
            [1] => 11:00 PM-12:30 AM
            [2] =>
            [3] => 1.5
            [4] => Sportsnet 360
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459724400
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => The Wheel Highlights
            [1] => 10:00 PM-11:00 PM
            [2] =>
            [3] => 1
            [4] => Sportsnet 360
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459720800
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => CHL Hockey 
            [1] => 06:00 PM-09:00 PM
            [2] => Brandon @ Edmonton
            [3] => 3
            [4] => Sportsnet 360
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 1459706400
        )
    ) 
)
```

My desired output is like this:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => Rugby 
                [1] => 05:00am-07:30 AM 
                [2] => National Rugby League Titans vs Broncos
                [3] => 2.5 
                [4] => SNWorld
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459485000 
            ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [0] => Rugby
                [1] => 03:00 PM-05:15 PM
                [2] => Super League Rugby - Wolves v Warriors
                [3] => 2.25
                [4] => SNOverflow
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459522800 
            ) 
            [2] => Array (
                [0] => Cycling
                [1] => 03:30 PM-04:00 PM
                [2] => Criterium International
                [3] => 0.5
                [4] => SN1
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459524600 
            )
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => BPL Soccer
                [1] => 07:30 AM-09:45 AM
                [2] => Aston Villa v Chelsea
                [3] => 2.25
                [4] => SNRegions
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459582200
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => Rugby
                [1] => 09:45 AM-12:00 PM
                [2] => Super League Rugby - Red Devils v E
                [3] => 2.25
                [4] => SNOverflow
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459590300 
            )
            [2] => Array (
                [0] => Rugby
                [1] => 12:00 PM-02:00 PM
                [2] => Super League Rugby - Vikings v Dragons
                [3] => 2
                [4] => SNOverflow
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459598400 
            )
        ) 
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => CHL Hockey 
                [1] => 06:00 PM-09:00 PM
                [2] => Brandon @ Edmonton
                [3] => 3
                [4] => Sportsnet 360
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459706400
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => The Wheel Highlights
                [1] => 10:00 PM-11:00 PM
                [2] =>
                [3] => 1
                [4] => Sportsnet 360
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459720800
            )
            [2] => Array (
                [0] => The Wheel Highlights
                [1] => 11:00 PM-12:30 AM
                [2] =>
                [3] => 1.5
                [4] => Sportsnet 360
                [5] => 100
                [6] => 1459724400
            )
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: Hi, Muzamil, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: You have three levels. First level remains untouched? Otherwise, can you show your desired output?

Comment: Yep there are three levels, 1st level represents 1st day, and so on...
There are shown just three levels but in real it may contain more than 50 level (days)
So, what i want is to sort each levels entries according the timestamp at the 6th index of each entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your code has failed due to multi levels array. To sort items of each first level you have to perform a `foreach` on the first level and process it **by reference**, otherwise the sort result doesn't affect main array:

```php
#                  ↓ “&” means “by reference”
foreach( $array as &$sub )
{
    usort ( $sub, function( $a, $b ) { return $a[6] - $b[6]; } );
}
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/550209)**</kbd>